Ubuntu doesn't power off completely
I am running ubuntu 24.04 and when I click the poweroff button top right corner, it doesn't fully shutdown. The screen goes off but the power light is still on and it seems to be still running because the laptop got very hot when I put it like that in my backpack.
When I run systemctl poweroff from terminal it works and fully shuts down.
Anyone knows how to fix this?
EDIT: the gnome desktop power off button, not physical one. Sorry for confusion.

Some systems assign functions to the system power button.  Those function may be an actual power down (which would be like pulling the power cord out of the wall on a desktop system, some initiate a power-down, some will respond with a message "Did you really mean to power-down".
Doing something such as systemctl poweroff or sudo shutdown -P now are direct commands that would actually cause the system to power off.
In short, the power button at the upper right, while providing 'power-on' does not always mean it will do the opposite unless you not only push it but hold it down for several seconds.

is it about the gnome ui power button or physical power button?
